# Errors with Maven install on a project

Tags: maven

I'm trying to install Maven on a project (with mvn clean install) but I have some errors and I don't know what they mean.
Here is the screen shot of the cmd :

[image]

I also add the right environment variables for maven (M2, M2_HOME and MAVEN_OPTS). 
Can someone help me and tell me what it means please ?

Answer (score 0):

It means that your dependency to `eu.akka.jbossas:jboss-as-client:7.1.7.Final` that you have specified in your POM is not available at Maven central. Do you have the jar file available somewhere?

If that is the case, run this:

`mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<your jar file> -DgroupId=eu.akka.jbossas -DartifactId=jboss-as-client -Dversion=7.1.7.Final -Dpackaging=jar`

Please bear in mind that this means that only the machine you are running on will be able to build your project. If other developers/machines also need to build this project, consider installing a central repository at your site, such as Nexus or Artifactory, and upload the jar file there. You will then also need to make Maven aware that it should fetch the dependencies from there.

Comment: I don't have the jar file and in the central, the repository doesn't exist anymore. It's not my project, somebody else did it 10 years ago. So it can't work on my machine ?

Comment: I change the environment variable JAVA_HOME with a jre and not a jdk because my Eclipse didn't want to open. And I have others errors with this project and 2 of my 4 projects are working. The new error is "Failed to delete directory ..\target Reason : Unable to delete file ..\target\classes\Utilisateur.hbm.xml" What does that mean ?

Comment: Well, you absolutely need the same jar if you need to reproduce a previous build. Do you happen to know which classes your project needs from this jar? There might be other distributions (that have other Maven coordinates) that might work out for you.

Comment: It usually means that you have a process (e.g. Windows Explorer or TextPad) that has the `Utilisataur.hbm.xml` file open.

Answer (score 0):

The error tells you that the maven dependency `eu.akka.jbossas:jboss-as-client` doesn't exist. I've checked [the url](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/eu/) where it should be and it doesn't exist.

You should check other dependencies. For example the one maven provides:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.as</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-as-appclient</artifactId>
    <version>7.1.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

If you've got the jar local, you can create a maven-dependency by using [this guide](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html).